# How to "cascade delete" children without deleting parent?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11, cascade

I have a table, let's call it **parent**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE parent (
    id          TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    name        TEXT,
    description TEXT,
    -- other parent attributes
    created_at  TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL,
    updated_at  TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL
);
```

It has a number of child tables, let's say **child_1**, **child_2**, ... **child_n**. They all look something like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE child_n (
    id        BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    parent_id TEXT NOT NULL REFERENCES parent (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    -- other columns of child_n attributes
);
```

Some of these children may even have child tables of their own.

When I update a row in parent, I often want to also replace all of its descendants (ie: its children, their children, and so on recursively), as they are only relevant to the older version of that parent row.

My plan was to rely on that `REFERENCES parent (id) ON DELETE CASCADE`, but that only works if I actually delete the parent. I know I can delete and insert in a transaction, but this makes preserving the values of columns (like `created_at`) more awkward.

Is there a way to trigger the cascading delete of children without actually deleting the parent row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply re-insert deleted records:

```sql
WITH cte AS ( DELETE
              FROM parent
              WHERE {conditions}
              RETURNING * )
INSERT INTO parent
SELECT *
FROM cte;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=ade85a20de0bd8570bce4bea5a151381)